# Astro.js - Pass dynamic variables to pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, astrojs

So my problem is, i created page in Astro.js, i collect data from directus SDK, to propagate them on the site. I using buildin pagination in Astro.js. The problem showin up when i trying add some filtration. How can I rebuild pagination, i understand that pagination is rendered when sit is loading, but refresh dousn't rebuild it.

My pagination implementation:

```
export async function getStaticPaths({ paginate }) 
{
  const items = await fetchItems(filterValue);
  return paginate(items, { pageSize: 9 });
}
```

function fetchItems() fetching data from directus sdk. Function don't see declared veriable outside getStaticPath function.
I want to make filterValue dynamic. Can i do this or have to builb pagination by my own?

Comment: what exactly is your question? what do you mean with "I want to make filterValue dynamic"? what have you tried and what happened?

Comment: note, docs on this are https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#pagination